# How to split by word in java

Tags: java, split

I want to get the word "test" from following URL. how can i get it in Java.

```
http://google.com/test/index.htm
```

I may or may not know the word "test"

I have tried following:-

1. Method1

   ```
   String[] p = s.split("/");

   System.out.println("test" + p[0]);

   System.out.println("test" + p[1]);
   ```

o/p:-

```
http:/
http://google.com/test/index.htm
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to split it and return n-2 value like:

```
String[] myUrlSplits = string.split("/");
if (myUrlSplits.length > 2) {
    return myUrlSplits[myUrlSplits.length - 2];
}
//throw exception or return default value.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to split the string by "/"

```
    "http://google.com/test/index.htm".split("/")[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String url = "http://google.com/test/index.htm";
System.out.println(url.split("/")[3]);
```

Update: when you split using "/" character you'll get an array of String the element you want is the fourth one, as the first index of the array is zero, 3 will give you the `test`

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, you always should provide some explanation for why it does so.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.